# How to count substring of a string has appeared in another large string?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a large string like " ali li vali bali", and I want to know that how many times all words(I mean individual words like li) are repeated (ali, li, vali and bali are only considered as substrings) apart from its own existence.

For example: li is substring in a large string and it is repeating thrice other than its own existence.

li in ali, li in vali and li in bali. count is: 3.

**This is my code and the error I got:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str="";
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            str+= scan.nextLine();
        } 
        int n= str.trim().split("\\s+").length;
        String[] wordsArray=str.split(" ");
        substring sub=new substring();
        for(int i=0;i<wordsArray.length;i++){
            int count=sub.sub(wordsArray[i],str);
            csub+=count;
        }
        System.out.println("number of substring: "+csub);
```

**and substring do:**

```
public class substring{
    public int sub(String str,String str2){
        String[] wordsArray=str2.split(" ");
        int len=str.length();
        int b=0;
        String[] str1=new String[len*2+2];
        int k=0;
        for (int from = 0; from < str.length(); from++) {
            for (int to = from + 1; to <= str.length(); to++) {
                str1[k]=str.substring(from, to);
                k++;
            }
        }
        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<str1.length;i++){
            if(str1[i].length()>2){
                while ((index = str2.indexOf(str1[i], index)) != -1) {
                    index += str1[i].length();
                    count++;
                    b++;
                }
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

```
**I got this error:**                 
Expection in thread "main" java lang.NullPointerExpection                    
at substring.sub<substring.java:20>                                   
at main.main<main.java:52>
```

Comment: Which line is line 20?

Comment: And goodness gracious, indent your code man. And capitalize your class names.

Comment: in substring: count++;

Comment: Indentation is sometimes lost when posting to SO. It's not always that OP didn't indent his code....

Comment: Oh god: str+= scan.nextLine();. That poor string.

Comment: After *assuming* csub is supposed to be initialized to 0, it now compiles. But it does not throw the exception as you state. It does ***nothing***. It hangs, because it wants your input, and never stops asking for your input. I don't know what code your running, but it's not  what you posted.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter Never mind, is a StringBuilder in the bytecode anyways ;-)

Comment: when you input your all strig like above; press Enter, then press and hold crt+z and then press Enter.

Answer (score 1):

You can just scan the string without splitting it.

Example:

```
public static int countSubstring(String str, String substring) {
    // start at the beggining of the string
    int pos = 0; 
    int count = 0;

    // search starting at pos and store the index (if found) on pos
    while ((pos = str.indexOf(substring, pos)) != -1) {
        count++;

        // pos is at the index of last found substring
        // advance it by the length of the substring
        pos = pos + substring.length();
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countSubstring("li, vali and bali", "li"));
}
```

Output

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this,

```
public static int sub(String str, String str2) {
    if (str == null || str2 == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    int p = str2.indexOf(str);
    while (p >= 0) {
        count++;
        p = str2.indexOf(str, p + str.length());
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String toSearch = "Hi Dee Hi";
    System.out.println(sub("Hi", toSearch));
    System.out.println(sub("Dee", toSearch));
    System.out.println(sub("Ho", toSearch));
}
```

Outputs

```
2
1
0
```